# Router navigation loader delay problem - how to invoke it manually

Tags: angular

The loader shows up if loading = true, when the routerLink on the webpages are clicked.
It works every where but in the below component it shows up with a delay of half a second  because of this `this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/invoice',res.body.data.id]);` 
It takes half a second to fetch data from the back end which is the dynamic id when the id is fetched only then the route gets activated. Therefore the delay. 
How do I solve this ?
Is there a way to invoke NavigationStart event as soon as `createInvoice` function runs so it doesn't have the response  delay.

html

```
<button (click)="createInvoice(details)" class="select-plan">Choose Plan</button>
```

.

```
 createInvoice(plan: any){
        this.auth.createInvoice(plan).subscribe((res:any)=>{
          if(res.status==200) {
            if(res.body.data.id){
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/invoice',res.body.data.id]); 
            } 
          }
        }, (err)=>{
        })
      }
```

App Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, Event, NavigationCancel, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  loading = true;
  constructor(private router: Router) { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event)=>{
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loading = true;
      }
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationError){
         this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible.  To work around this, I would suggest decoupling your loading state from your router state.  The current implementation assumes that the loading is only updated in response to route changes, while in reality it can be changed by a number of things (in this example, API requests).
Creating a separate `LoadingService` to manage this state would allow you to update the state from anywhere in the application.  This also allows consumers anywhere in the application to be notified of loading events.  That would look something like this:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoadingService {

  // Create subject with initial state of true (assumed from default value of AppComponent.loading)
  private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);

  // Expose the subject as an Observable, allowing consumers to subscribe to be notified of changes
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

  setLoading(loading: boolean) {
    // Update the loading subject
    this.loadingSubject.next(loading);
  }

}
```

The service above uses a BehaviorSubject to track the current loading state.  It exposes the subject as an Observable, allowing consumers to subscribe to changes.

Instead of updating a local variable when the route changes, the injected service would be updated:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router, private loadingService: LoadingService) { 
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event)=>{
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true);
      }
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel || 
         routerEvent instanceof NavigationError){
         this.loadingService.setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Now that the state is managed in the service, we no longer have to rely solely on route changes to update the loading state.  You can inject the loading service anywhere and update the state just as we did in the AppComponent above:

```
createInvoice(plan: any){
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true); // Set the loading state directly

        this.auth.createInvoice(plan).subscribe((res:any)=>{
          if(res.status==200) {
            if(res.body.data.id){
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/invoice',res.body.data.id]); 
            } 
          }
        }, (err)=>{
        })
      }
```

Comment: Great solution, works after subscribing to the observable `if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loadingService.setLoading(true); 
this.loadingService.loading$.subscribe((res)=>{ this.loading = res;})`                                                                   
      }